# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null. http request

Tags: http, dart

I am new to flutter. when I run my code , I got the error

```
E/flutter (16181): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error 
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null.
E/flutter (16181): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16181): Tried calling: get("192.168.1.6:8080/resturant/food/allFood") occurred in Instance of 'MenuBloc'.
E/flutter (16181): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (16181): #1      FoodApiClient.fetchAllFood (package:restuarant_app/Repository/FoodApiClient.dart:16:49)
E/flutter (16181): #2      FoodRepository.getAllFood (package:restuarant_app/Repository/FoodRepository.dart:12:28)
E/flutter (16181): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16181): #3      MenuBloc.mapEventToState (package:restuarant_app/Bloc/menue_bloc/menu_bloc.dart:30:38)
E/flutter (16181): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16181): #4      Bloc._bindEventsToStates.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:232:20)
E/flutter (16181): #5      Stream.asyncExpand.onListen.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:579:30)
E/flutter (16181): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (16181): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (16181): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (16181): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (16181): #10     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:594:14)
E/flutter (16181): #11     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
E/flutter (16181): #12     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
E/flutter (16181): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (16181): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16181): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (16181): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (16181): #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (16181): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (16181): #19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (16181): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (16181): #21     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (16181): #22     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (16181): 
E/flutter (16181): #0      Cubit.onError.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/cubit.dart:140:7)
E/flutter (16181): #1      Cubit.onError (package:bloc/src/cubit.dart:141:6)
E/flutter (16181): #2      Bloc.onError (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:113:11)
E/flutter (16181): #3      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)
E/flutter (16181): #4      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (16181): #5      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:995:7)
E/flutter (16181): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError
```

I would like to get data from remote server.
This is FoodRepository code.

```
class FoodRepository{
  final foodDao=new FoodDao();
  final foodApiClient =new FoodApiClient();
  Future<List<Food>> getAllFood() async{
    if(await checkInternetConnection()) {
      print("fetch data from remote server");
     return  foodApiClient.fetchAllFood();
    }else{
     print("from db");
     return foodDao.getAllFood();
   }

  }
}
```

This is FoodApiClient code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:restuarant_app/Model/Food.dart';
class FoodApiClient{
  static const baseUrl = '192.168.1.6';
  final http.Client httpClient;

  FoodApiClient({@required this.httpClient});
  Future<List<Food>> fetchAllFood()async{
    String url=":8080/resturant/food/allFood";
   
    List<Food> foodList;
    print(url);
    final allFoodResponse=await this.httpClient.get(baseUrl+url);
    print(allFoodResponse);
    if (allFoodResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('An error occured while loading food list!!! status code: '+allFoodResponse.statusCode.toString());
    }
    print("foodJson");
    List foodJson = json.decode(allFoodResponse.body);
    print(foodJson);
    //foodJson.forEach((food) {foodList.add(Food.fromJson(food)); });
    foodList=foodJson.map((f)=>Food.fromJson(f)).toList();
    return   foodList;
  }

}
```

I got this error on `final allFoodResponse=await this.httpClient.get(baseUrl+url);`I want to make get http request.

I know the error explained that httpClient is null but I don't know why it is null and how to fix this error.

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it? Theres no information, just "XMLHttpRequest error."